# Filemaker Server 14 will not start webserver on Mac OSX 10.10

Tags: macos, apache, filemaker

I am running Filemaker Server 14 on Mac OS X 10.10. I upgraded from FMS 13 on Mac OS X 10.9 and I could not even get the Admin Console. Probably because of a Java issue. So I upgraded to OS X 10.10. I then could get to the Admin Console.

The issue here is I am running the built-in Apache also. The server has 3 IP addresses. After I installed FMS 14 everything worked fine. Then I configured the built-in Apache to use 2 of the IPs. I configured FMS 14 for the remaining IP in

```
/Library/FileMaker Server/HTTPServer/conf/httpd.conf
```

I entered this into the FMS conf:

```
Listen 85.196.85.67:80 ## one of the servers IPs
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

I restarted fmsadmin stop/start server and built-in Apache. Apache is running fine on the remaining IPs. But FMS 14 will not run its webserver. In the Admin panel it says the web connection port is 12700180 (!!) Seems it does not understand the conf setting I put in.
[image: webserver not running]

I have tried turn off the built-in Apache and even entered into FMS http.conf this:

```
Listen 80
```

Still no luck. Every time I do a change I try to run "fmsadmin stop/start server" and even tried a restart. Still I am not able to get the FMS webserver running.
I guess I am editing the correct conf file for FMS? I see there is also a file "httpd.conf.2.4" in the con directory and it is updated with the changes I do in http.conf.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do a clean reinstall of FM Server. It is not as bad as it sounds, you can back up configuration in the admin console (remember to enable popups in safari). Then stop the database server, move your data files out and delete the /Library/FileMaker folder.

When you run the installer, it should put everything back in place where it should go... I've had this issue a couple times on OS X now and this fixed it.

You should probably stop the other instances of apache first and try to enable them after, but this configuration is not supported, so it could be that after a restart things do not come back up in the right order or something. Good luck.

Comment: I understand this is and unsupported scenario but I got everything working fine with FM Server 13 along with Apache built-in. Why will it not work with FM Server 14? The problem is I don't have two machines. So if it could work, what is the way to do this correctly? How do I get FM Server 14 to only run on one IP and not the other two I have? Where do I configure this and in what steps?